# Is it possible to remotely call methods on another computer through AIDL (Android Interface Definition Language)?

Tags: android, call, aidl

I am curious whether the AIDL only serves for inter-process communication between several Android apps on the same device, or AIDL provides much wider functionality. Let's say I have a Java application running on some server, is it possible to remotely call methods on that server through AIDL from an Android phone?

If yes, do I need some extra libraries on the server-side Java application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it possible to remotely call
>   methods on that server through AIDL
>   from an Android phone?

There is nothing built into Android to support this, sorry.

Comment: Do you know perhaps of any 3rd party library which would make that possible? And would there be any potential problems when converted to Dalvik format?

Comment: @user395744: I am no idea, sorry.