# Building a server to an android application

Tags: java, android

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300089/is-it-possible-to-remotely-call-methods-on-another-computer-through-aidl-androi) thread which actually looks for the same thing that i look - but he didnt got answered.
What i'm looking for is a way to connect between server (as a java application) and a client (as a android application) - in a way that the client will be able to call remote methods in the server, and get remote objects from the server. (doesn't matter if it uses AIDL or not..)

I worked with RMI and it's fine - but it unnable to use on Android, so i have to find another way.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible avenues:

1. Use servlets on the server and pass data via GET/POST
2. JAX - pass data via SOAP requests

I'm sure there are others, too.

Comment: thank you. do you know what is the stantard way in my situation?

Comment: #1 would probably be more straightforward. #2 more versatile and offering additional security (if needed).